# How do i use each key and value to send back and differenet string or http?

Tags: c#

This is how i'm using my web server in form1:

```
WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://+:8098/");
ws.Run();
```

And the method:

```
static string[] values = null;
public static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
{
    foreach (string value in request.QueryString.AllKeys)
    {
        values = request.QueryString.GetValues(value);
    }
    return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page.<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);
}
```

In request.QueryString i can get all the values and also AllKeys.
I send from java client code a parameter for example:

```
String urlStr="http://10.0.0.2:8098/?cmd=startrecording";
```

So the key is cmd and the value is startrecording
But there might be a case i sent another parameter to the server for example:

```
String urlStr="http://10.0.0.2:8098/?cmd=startrecording&danny=1234567890";
```

Now i have two keys in AllKeys i haeb cmd and danny
And two values startrecord and 1234567890

My problem is how do i handle the keys and values inside the SendResponse method ?

I want to do something that if the key is cmd and the value is startrecording do something and return a string for this action.

And if the key is danny and the value is 1234567890 do something else and return a differenet string or return a html. How do i handle in this metho the keys and values ?

If it's needed this is my WebServer code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Youtube_Manager
{
    class WebServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

        public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

            // URI prefixes are required, for example 
            // "http://localhost:8080/index/".
            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

            // A responder method is required
            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("method");

            foreach (string s in prefixes)
                _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

            _responderMethod = method;
            _listener.Start();
        }

        public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
            : this(prefixes, method) { }

        public void Run()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
                try
                {
                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                        {
                            var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                            try
                            {
                                string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(ctx.Request.QueryString);
                                //ctx.Request.QueryString

                                byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                            }
                            catch { } // suppress any exceptions
                            finally
                            {
                                // always close the stream
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                            }
                        }, _listener.GetContext());
                    }
                }
                catch { } // suppress any exceptions
            });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _listener.Stop();
            _listener.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this change : values = values.Concat(request.QueryString.GetValues(value));

Comment: You actually need a response that looks like this : "<HTML><BODY><Values><Value>abc</Value><Value>def</Value><Value>ghi</Value></Values></BODY></HTML>"

Comment: I can't response with a simple string for example: return "ok" ?

Comment: And what about what i'm getting the keys and values how do i handle them ? I'm getting a key and it's value and i want to check and make that once i'm getting for example a key cmd and it's value is "start" then do something. And if i'm getting more keys then do something else and also return something else. I want that each key and it's value will response another string.

Comment: Then add more tags  or use attributes : "<HTML><BODY><Values><Value><Key>a</Key><Prefix>abc</Prefix></Value><Value><Key>d</Key><Prefix>def</Prefix></Value><Value><Key>g</Key><Prefix>ghi</Prefix></Value></Val‌​ues></BODY></HTML>"